# Popover tableview frame issue

Tags: ios7, xamarin

I have filled popover with tableview. First time it's showing perfectly. Once i changed the focus and reload the popover that time tableview frame is getting changed. i haven't given tableview frame anywhere in my app.

Comment: Can you provide us some code? How you exactly init and show your popover?